# RoR: How to merge an order on two columns into an ActiveRecord query?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sorting

I'm trying to sort a table based on several columns so that the resulting order represents the fields interlaced.

ie,

users has first_name:string and last_name:string, account has historical_first_name, and historical_last_name, and belongs to User. If user has a first_name, it should override historical_first_name when listing accounts (ie, a user either has set their name or they have a historical name on an account).

I'm trying to return an ordered list of accounts based on first name and last name ASC, either historical or set on the user. The result should be an ActiveRecord relation and not an array.

This query does not achieve what I want:

```
@accounts = @accounts.includes(:user).order("users.first_name ASC, historical_first_name ASC, users.last_name ASC, users.last_name ASC")
```

Because any historical_first_names are that are alphabetically before first_names are sorted after all first_name. How would you write something that achieves an order like this:

```
Amanda Adams <- migration_first_name: Amanda, user.first_name: nil 
Bentley James <- migration_first_name: nil, user.first_name: Bentley
Cynthia Cann <- migration_first_name: Cynthia, user.first_name: nil
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to order primarily by the first_name, or the historical_first_name if that is null. And then after that order by last_name, or historical_last_name if that is null.

You can use the `COALESCE()` function (or `IFNULL()`) to represent that.

```
@accounts = @accounts.includes(:user).order(
  "COALESCE(users.first_name, users.historical_first_name) ASC",
  "COALESCE(users.last_name, users.historical_last_name) ASC"
)
```